# Wireless adb with android <11

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, adbwireless

I want to load apps from Android Studio onto my phone.  I don't want to use a usb cable for reasons (my charge port has debris or something in it).

If I had android 11, I could go to Developer Settings and scan a qr or type a code to load code wirelessly.  My phone doesn't support android 11, and I don't really want to jam in an OS that isn't supported by the vendor.

Am I SOL?  Are there other ways to get a wireless adb?  (Or do I have to go spend money in the physical realm to fix my charge port?)

Comment: This method need at least a quick setup through USB https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/10202308 . There might be another solution, I use it when I have a limited computer, is testing through VMs on the phone through wifi (for example Vmos offers virtual machines of android on android phones and you can use adb wireless with. if I remember well, for Android version 5 & 7)

Comment: If the USB port is blocked shut it down and carefully remove everything inside using a needle. For dust and fluff you can use a compressed air spray.